# How can I read and display a list of maps from a REST service?

Tags: angular, rest

I need to read in and display from a list of maps from a REST service. If I could just manage to read a single variable from the objects stored in the maps, I should be able to finish my project.

I tried to read the maps into an array and use *ngFor to cycle through each map to read the name variable of the objects stored in the maps.

REST Service Content

```
{"testmap1":

[{"name":"testObject1","boolean1":true,"boolean2":true,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test"},
{"name":"testObject2","boolean1":false,"boolean2":false,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test2"}],

"testmap2":

[{"name":"testObject3","boolean1":false,"boolean2":false,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test3"},
{"name":"testObject4","boolean1":false,"boolean2":true,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test4"}]}
```

app.home.ts

```js
array: any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://myURLhere/retrieve').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.array = data as any[];
        console.log(this.array);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

app.home.html

```html
    <table *ngIf="array">
      <tr *ngFor="let map of array">
        <td *ngFor="let object of map">{{object.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

My code results in:

```
Doing this resulted in the error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I expected to have a table displaying `mapObject1` and `mapObject2`. The table generates with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we have an object of objects. We can utilize the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe provided by angular to iterate object properties. So your assignment of data is correct, except `array` will be an object. Here I initialize it, so we don't need the `*ngIf` in the template. I usually initialize all variables, but that is only a recommendation.

```ts
array = {};

this.http.get('http://myURLhere/retrieve').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.array = data;
    console.log(this.array);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
);
```

and template:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of array | keyvalue">
    <td *ngFor="let o of item.value">{{o.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5beae?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I **strongly** recommend you **type** your data instead of using `any`. We are using **Type**Script after all ;) Also makes your life so much easier. Also like mentioned in other answer, you should move the http-requests to a service, like I have done in below demo. Usually services handle these kinds of things, and component only subscribes to the data.

Comment: To clarify, I will have many maps of the form of "testMap" so I will need to read them all in at once so that I can iterate through all the maps.

Comment: Well for the current code you are showing, my solution should work. I don't have a crystal ball to see how your data is **going** to look like ;)

Comment: You need to show how your data is going to look like if you want an answer that suits your needs. I have no idea how your data will be structured if you don't show that.

Comment: So you say... `To clarify, I will have many maps of the form of "testMap"`. Please show a sample of JSON.

Comment: My issue is that I'm new to JSON so I am not sure how my list of maps will look with more entries.

Comment: Well, until then no-one can give you another solution. This is how you have to do it right now, with the data structure you have provided...

Comment: I am working on adding new data to the database; I will update the JSON soon.

Comment: Okay, I added a version with two maps.

Comment: One last question: is it somehow possible for me to display the map id? ("testmap1" for example)

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out, and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi in order to make your code cleaner, you should consider putting most of the logic in a service but to fix this.

You could do this

```
retrieveAll() {
  return this.http.get('http://myURLhere/retrieve')
  .pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("HTTP request has been triggered")),
  catchError(err => {
      console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
      return throwError(err);
    }));
 }

ngOnInit() {
  this.retrieveAll().subscribe(data => this.array = data,
  err => console.log('HTTP Error', err) // This enables you to console log errors from the subscription 
  );
}
```

Comment: When attempting to implement your code, I get the following error:               
                                                                                                                        
Argument of type '(res: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]'.
  Type '(res: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]': concat, join, slice, indexOf, and 15 more.ts(2345)

Comment: Ooh i see, although i mostly recommend creating a modal first when consuming your API. but the problem i mapped the object itself. i just edited the code try it now

Comment: Thanks for the help; still a few issues though: cannot find name 'tap' or 'res' and property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: It's very fine, Tap is not a necessity though it's just an rxjs function for logging or knowing when an observable has been triggered or clicked. to fix that you should import it with this     import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';       meanwhile i realized i made a mistake in a few lines of code please check back i have updated it. Sorry about that

Comment: Please kindly check now, i will be awaiting your feedback.

Comment: Down to two error messages: 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' and Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>' (this second error referring to console.log(err)).

Comment: ooh damn am sorry, you are supposed to pass the error in the subscription, i did that because as for me i do have an error service that catches all the errors which is why i passed that. i will update the code asap and will share my error service if you may need it or find it helpful

Comment: To clarify, I will have many maps of the form of "testMap" so I will need to read them all in at once so that I can iterate through all the maps.

Comment: Updated it, kindly check. pardon me multitasking over here

Comment: That's fine, ones you have your your data, iterating the object will be successful

Comment: Still getting the error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: i just went through the code and realized return is missing, kindly add that and it will fix that. i have updated it as well

Comment: With 'this.array' highlighted: "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?"

Comment: No don't use an array, just use a variable any, like array: any;

Comment: meanwhile i always recommend having a model to represent your data, since you are new to json. show me what your API payload i will model it for you